# Creating multiple zip files with PHP

Tags: symfony, laravel-5

I have a problem in PHP / Laravel to create multiple zip files synchronously, I copy all commands that is generated and squeeze into the Shell, it executes normally, but when I step into the PHP run it only generates the first file = /.

Controller code.

```
foreach ($passwords as $p){
        if($i == 0){
            $command = 'zip -u -j -P '.$p.' '.$dir.'/'.$count.'.zip '.storage_path().'/app/'.$directory.'/'.$file1->getClientOriginalName();
            $commands->push($command);
        }else{
            $command = 'zip --quiet -j -P '.$p.' '.$dir.'/'.$count.'.zip '.storage_path().'/app/'.$directory.'/'.($count+1).'.zip';
            $commands->push($command);
        }
        $count--;
        $i++;
    }
    foreach ($commands as $p){
        echo $p.'<br/>';
    }
    foreach ($commands as $c){
        $process = new Process($c);
        $process->start();
        sleep(10);
        if($process->isTerminated()){
            sleep(1);
        }
        if ($errorOutput = $process->getErrorOutput()) {
            throw new RuntimeException('Process: ' . $errorOutput);
        }
    }
```

[Data $commands](https://pastebin.com/xwuEYb1X)

The script only generates the file 50.zip.

Comment: Have you checked file permission of files to be zipped? What about the size? Have you checked that `50.zip` to be valid ZIP file?

Comment: If I copy all commands and paste to the shell, they generate 50 files normally. I checked the permissions, each file has 1kb.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if `sleep` could interfere with subprocess (shell command). Please try:

```
foreach ($commands as $c){
    $process = new Process($c);
    // Set the timeout instead of sleeping
    $process->setTimeout(10);
    $process->start();

    // Wait for the process to finish
    $process->wait();

    if ($errorOutput = $process->getErrorOutput()) {
        throw new RuntimeException('Process: ' . $errorOutput);
    }
}
```

`wait()` call uses `usleep` in a more fine-grained manner it *might* help with that.

Does it work like this?